# Custom taxonomy displayed in search results

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

In my search results template within my WP site `search.php`, the function `et_divi_post_meta()` displays a posts meta data.

What code would I use to display the the custom taxonomy that I created: `'State'` and `'Product-Type'`?

So search results sould include that info and not just: the title, meta and the_content.

Example:

> **Special Price**
>
> Monday's Special Price on wall paper is...
>
> *-Illinois
>
> -Wall Paper*

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php
                        
    et_divi_post_meta();
if ( 'on' !== et_get_option( 'divi_blog_style', 'false' ) )
    truncate_post( 270 );
    else
    the_content();
    ?>
//
```

Here is the taxonomy Code

```
// Add custom taxonomies
add_action( 'init', 'specials_create_taxonomies', 0 );

function specials_create_taxonomies() 
{
    // Town
    $town_labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Town', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Town', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search in Town' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Towns' ),
        'most_used_items' => null,
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Town' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Town' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new Town' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Town' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Town' ),

    );
    register_taxonomy('town', 'specials', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $town_labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Town' )
    
    ));
```

Comment: Indent your code by 4 spaces please. Whats the code you used to create the taxonomies?

Comment: I fixed your mark up and parts of the content. Please keep in mind: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all, I found my answer here, using 'get_the_terms()' --> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Comment: How do I mark as a 'closed/resolved topic'?